# ¿Por qué mi aplicación no me detecta JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Buenas, tengo un estoy intentando hacer un fadeToggle de JQuery pero no sé por qué no me funciona, no sé si me podríais ayudar.

hago en el head la llamada a la librería de JQuery (la cual me la han pasado para que la ponga así y no me descargue la libreria)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="contenedor">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="menu">Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="content">
            <div id="lateral"></div>
        </section>
        <footer></footer>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('entra funcion');
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#lateral").fadeToggle(2000);
    });
});
```

estoy intentando mostrar u ocultar ese div pero al no me entra ni en la función ya qe ni me salta el alert y no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o no.

Me podríais ayudar?
Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Estas insertando JQuery dentro de la cabecera, es decir, dentro de las etiquetas `head`? He probado tu ejemplo y entra en la función.

Comment: He reproducido tu ejemplo y funciona correctamente. Lo puedes ver [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/8qox83ne/)

Comment: si, dentro de las etiquetas head hago la llamada al jquery como lo he puesto arriba y al js donde tengo metida la función <script type="text/javascript" src="js/archivo.js"></script> y no me salta ni el alert que tengo metido en la funcion, por eso preguntaba

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el orden en el que lo tienes introducido? Tendrías que poner en primer lugar el JQuery y en segundo lugar tu javascript personal, ya que si no no te va a funcionar ya que este segundo javascript necesita del primero para funcionar.

Comment: vale, ha sido eso, tonto de mi, estaba puesto al reves, primero el js y despues el jquery, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, ha sido un placer ayudar :)

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta dada como solución, de forma que la pregunta no aparezca como _sin resolver_. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tras ver que tu ejemplo funcionaba correctamente y comentarme que tenías tu `Javascript` en un fichero externo, el problema puede ser porque hayas insertado erróneamente el orden de los ficheros dentro de tus etiquetas `head`.

Para que un fichero externo en el que utilizas JQuery funcione correctamente, el orden es muy importante, **ya que JQuery tiene que ir siempre en primer lugar**, para que el resto de ficheros externos que necesiten usarlo puedan utilizarlo sin problemas.

Quedaría algo así:

```
<head>
   //Etiqueta script con JQuery
   //Etiqueta script con tu fichero externo
   //Otra etiqueta script con otro fichero externo
</head>
```

En el caso de que quisieras añadir más ficheros externos, tendrías que agregarlos debajo de estos y, en el supuesto caso de que algún fichero necesitara utilizar las funciones de otro, deberías de añadir el fichero que contiene las funciones en primer lugar.